# Can we use AWS amplify only for its react library (components) but not the backend cli?

Tags: reactjs, serverless-framework, aws-amplify

We are trying to use amplify only for the react components in its library. But as we understand, Amplify is more of a serverless backend configuration tool `amplify-cli`, see https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react

Can we use our own backend configuration such as serverless.com

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Install the package using `npm` and follow the JavaScript documentation within your React app.

```
npm i aws-amplify --save
```

Here is my configuration to use Cognito and API Gateway:

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    identityPoolId: process.env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
    mandatorySignIn: true
  },
  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: 'API',
        endpoint: process.env.API_URL,
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
        custom_header: async () => (
          { Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession()).idToken.jwtToken}` }
        )
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

This lets you call your serverless backend endpoints like so:

```
import { API } from 'aws-amplify'

const data = await API.get('API', '/posts')
```

The JWT configuration allows your serverless endpoints to use the authorizer type `COGNITO_USER_POOLS` to authorize endpoint usage.